# Implementing observer design pattern and handling the messages

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I am using observer design pattern and updating the GUI from model which is working great. For each operation or function call from GUI, the model sends a series of updates at various stages to notify the GUI accordingly to do updates. This resulted in rather big if-else block in UpdateView() method. Is this how it should be or can this improved by applying another design pattern? I have split message from each function to a different handler which helps quite a bit. Note: the code is not compiled below but i took the essence of what I am doing. I have studied design patterns for a while but I am implementing it for the first time.

```
class Msg
{
   int operation; 
   int opCode;
}

// in the model class
Device::Calibrate()
{
   Msg msg;
   msg.operation = CALIBRATE;

    // ..... do some work -----
   msg.opCode = DEPENDENT_MODULE_NOT_LOADED;
   Notify( msg )

   // .... do some work ------
   msg.opCode = HARDWARE_MODULE_1_FAILED
   Notify( msg )

   // .... do some work ------
   msg.opCode = CALIBRATION_IN_PROGRESS
   Notify( msg )

   // --- so on -----

}

void CMainDlg::UpdateView(const Msg * msg )
{
    if( msg->operation == VERIFY ) // all message from Verify() button pressed 
        OnVerify( msg );
    if( msg->operation == CALIBRATE ) // all messages from Calibrate button pressed
        OnCalibrate();
}

void CMainDlg::OnCalibrate(const Msg * msg)
{
    if (msg->opCode == DEPENDENT_MODULE_NOT_LOADED)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == HARDWARE_MODULE_1_FAILED)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == HARDWARE_MODULE_2_FAILED)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == CALIBRATION_IN_PROGRESS)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == OUTPUT_FILE_COULD_NOT_BE_CREATED)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == CALIBRATION_FAILED)
    {

    }
    else if msg->opCode == CALIBRATION_PASSED)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach. I assume it works for you, you're just wondering if there's a "better" way to do it?

Comment: @krsteeve Yes it works well and this way it's easy to copy custom notifications to other views as well. I am looking for just a 'better way', that's pretty much it!

Comment: sometimes a reference is to the model is passed to update. then the view can query the model.

Comment: @zadane This isn't strictly the observer pattern, but it accomplishes the same thing and looks like it works well for your needs. To avoid a bunch of if-statements, your listener interface could have functions for each case ie, OnDependentModuleNotLoaded, OnHardwareModule1Failed, etc. For your case - you're much more limited in how you can pass information through this "Notify" interface. Thus you are stuck collapsing the value then re-expanding

Comment: Another way is PostEvent instead of notify signal and CustomEvent to handle posted events in gui.  postevent from model is not standard. So code will be tightly coupled. but you can post to multiple widgets even. I think it would be faster than signal/slot connection. I am not sure, strength and weekness of signal/slot and postEvent/CustomEvent in your senario.

Comment: @krsteeve I actually didn't do that on purpose. I do think I have a legit observer working but I choose to implement only single method in my observer interface (`UpdateView`). This way my views implements just one method to comply with observer and dispatch them accordingly. Otherwise I would be overriding some 20 methods like you pointed and that seems like laborious work :)

Comment: @zadane Sorry, the boilerplate listener code must be missing for simplicity's sake, my mistake. Then yes, I do think your code is ideal - you will either be stuck with that giant if-block or many functions :)

Comment: @krsteeve Yes i didn't include that, thanks!